# Update in SQL from using a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, updating

I am a novice SQL learner and trying to do an update statement as like before

```
UPDATE STG
SET STG.COL1 = SUB.COL1
SET STG.COL2 = SUB.COL2
FROM TABLE AS STG
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MIN([DATE]) AS COL1, MAX([DATE]) AS COL2
            FROM TABLE
            GROUP BY ID) AS SUB ON STG.ID = SUB.ID
```

but I'm getting these errors:

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Line 4: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

I am using

```
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2066 (Intel X86) 
May 11 2012 18:41:14 
Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

Comment: SET STG.COL1 = SUB.COL1, STG.COL2 = SUB.COL2 use comma for multiple field updation

Comment: When you have an error and you ask a question about that error you need to include that error. Use the edit link on your question to include that detail, do not include it as a comment. Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `UPDATE` syntax depends on the database; tag with what database you're using.  Also, 'but getting error' is not informative; provide the actual error message.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 is ***beyond dead and unsupported*** .... you should **definitely** upgrade to a more recent version! Lots of features of newer version simply aren't available for such an antique version

Comment: Its my place uses it and I can't go and ask the HOD to change it.

Comment: Your table's name isn't table..right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 UPDATE STG
    SET STG.COL1 = SUB.COL1,STG.COL2 = SUB.COL2
    FROM TABLE  STG
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ID
    ,MIN([DATE]) AS COL1
    ,MAX([DATE]) AS COL2
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY ID 
    ) As SUB
    ON STG.ID = SUB.ID
```